# Option list in Smarty

Tags: php, html-select, smarty

[image]By using Smarty Template Engine I got confused, I wanted to retrieve records from database and put them into an option list.

That was simple in PHP

```
$sqlFrom = "SELECT * FROM howto_lang_From WHERE Activation=1";
$resultFrom = mysql_query($sqlFrom);

echo    '<select name="from" class="list" required>';
echo    '<option value="">Choose</option>';

while ($lanFrom = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultFrom)) {

      echo      "<option>$lanFrom[From]</option>";      
        }

echo    '</select>';
```

but in Smarty template I am not sure, tried something like this, but couldn't get it to work

```
**PHP:**
$sqlFrom = "SELECT * FROM howto_lang_From WHERE Activation=1";
$resultFrom = mysql_query($sqlFrom);

while ($lanfrom = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultFrom)) {
$result[] = $lanfrom;


}

$smarty->assign("FROM", "$result");

**Template:**
    <select name="from" class="list" required>
    <option value="">Choose</option>
{section name=from loop=$FROM}
        <option>{$FROM[from].From}</option>     
{/section}  
        </select>
```

and one more question!!
I am an average PHP programmer, after a glance on this template engine, I faced lots of confusion!! SO, DOES IT REALLY WORTH TO CREATE SITES DEPENDING ON SMARTY? is not the original way of combining PHP and HTML much easier and readable!?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a foreach instead of a section. Much easier if you're looping over an object http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

Comment: As for your primary question, the reason we use templates are to ensure the separation of front and back end concerns. Your logic shouldn't(and is very hard to) be put in templates, while putting display in the logic is similarly difficult. Your front end designer shouldn't care about your database engine/design by having to worry about `mysql_fetch_assoc` or a similar method.

Comment: I'd appreciate a further explanation )) {foreach from=$myArray item=foo}
    <li>{$foo}</li>
{/foreach}

Comment: Instead of your current: `{section name=from loop=$FROM} <option>{$FROM[from].From}</option> {/section}` You should instead do: `{foreach from=$FROM item=fromItem}<option>{$fromItem}</option>{/foreach}` Also I think you need to reconsider FROM as a naming value, it's kind of vague. If you're handling translations have you considered `inputLanguage` or something similar, much clearer on what you intend to use it for.

Comment: Ok, it is more clear now, but what about the part "item=fromItem" what should I set? Thanks for your advise, Really! why have not I named it "inputLanguage" sounds much easier! ))

Comment: now, it is something else, I tried this one: {foreach from=$FROM item=fromItem}<option>{$fromItem}</option>{/foreach} gave me an output "Array", so changed the <option>{$fromItem}</option> to <option>{$fromItem.From}</option> "according to database" but it gave me just the first "index" of the first word in database "A"

Comment: You'd have to share your table design for me to help with that issue.

Comment: I updated the post, check out the shot I've just added

Comment: I tried using {html_options options=$inputLanguage} but it gives the same output, "Array" but when I specify {html_options options=$inputLanguage.From} it give back "A" as it is the first letter of the first record!! Any more ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one problem with your code. You would knew about it if you had `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL`.

Using this line:

```
$smarty->assign("FROM", "$result");
```

You make that your `$result` array is being converted to string and if error_reporting is set properly you will get notice: `Notice: Array to string conversion in ...`

So it's enough to change this line into:

```
$smarty->assign("FROM", $result);
```

simply removing quotes.

You should also use `PDO` or `mysqli` as `mysql` is deprecated.

Is it worth to use templates? In my opinion - yes. They make you to separate logic from displaying data. You first get data and prepare them for displaying and than display it. Of course you can also do it in pure PHP but Smarty syntax (or other templates syntax) makes view to be easier skimmed or changed. However you need to learn template syntax, settings and so on and it's usually not so obvious.

Comment: Thank you for you response, I did as you explained but now I had a list where each of the options is named "Array",, I used the {debug} and got this

 $inputLanguage  Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Array (6)
  0 => Array (1)
    From => "Adygha (Kabardian)"
  1 => Array (1)
    From => "Arabic"
  2 => Array (1)
    From => "English"
  3 => Array (1)
    From => "German"
  4 => Array (1)
    From => "Russian"
  5 => Array (1)
    From => "Turkish"
->nocache = false
->scope = "file:index.tpl"

instead of the languages, I got "Array" "Array" "Array"

Comment: Ok, I went it through )) thank you sir, after following your post, I changed the template order from {foreach from=$inputLanguage item=fromItem}
<option>{$fromItem}</option>
{/foreach}

which was showing "Array" "Array" 5 times in the <option list> into,

{foreach from=$inputLanguage item=fromItem}
<option>{$fromItem.From}</option>
{/foreach}
which brought back the languages themselves, "English" "Russian" .... 

Thank you very much )) I'll need your support if I face something else )))